# SQL REPORTING Service (SSRS) won't start- Removing and reinstalling

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Thanks to someone who might have done something after which my SSRS services would not start. Increased the service timeout threshold, changed the service account, repaired the instance including SSRS but none revived it, checked the logs nothing specific to what might have caused the issue except that Application logs states- service started while System Logs indicates Service Terminated Unexpectedly.

Leaving that aside now i am on the road to completely remove SSRS for which i had couple of doubts:

1. Would i still require the encryption key, though i will be installing it again on the same server? (Report Config Manager is not accessible )
2. Will my custom reports be available in the report server databases?

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The encryption key is required in order to decrypt content after restoring the report server database (eg. datasources with saved username/password). Otherwise you have to reset encrypted content

Comment: When you say reset encrypted content, how do we go about it. Say i removed SSRS, reinstalled it, use the existing Report Server Databases and?

Comment: In encryption keys there is an option to delete encrypted content. I would suggest backup and restore both database and encryption key. Delete encrypted content if these is no alternative

Comment: Hope this is after i do the re installation and after old report databases are mapped? Because currently the Report Configuration manager is not accessible means i can't connect to it.

Any idea on my second question about the custom reports? Will those be available when the databases are restored?

Comment: After you restore the database, all reports and linked reports will be available. If there are execution errors, you ll probably have to update datasource credentials